# Trying to get a local node running on tails

Tags: full-node, linux

I tried to make a local node on my tails persistent storage using this guide :

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/h8pbc2/guide_setting_up_a_monero_full_node_on_tails/

when i start the app image made with this command:

printf "#\041/bin/bash\n\ export DNS_PUBLIC=tcp\n\ gnome-terminal -- bash -c \ "torsocks $PWD/monerod --no-igd \ --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 \ --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 \ --rpc-bind-port 17600 \ --data-dir /home/amnesia/Persistent/.bitmonero;\ read -p \\"Press enter to close\\""" > start-daemon.AppImage \ && sleep 1 && chmod +x start-daemon.AppImage

I get F Error starting server: Failed to bind IPv4 (set to required)

Any help would be appreciated

Regards

Comment: I just used the gui to download the blockchain on the persistent drive and had no issues.

Comment: @lex - Did you manage to resolve your issue?